# Issues adding a new field to task_struct in Android 11 Linux Kernel

Tags: linux

While modifying the Android 11 Linux kernel source code for my Pixel4 XL, I added a void* mydata field at the end of the task_struct structure. I did not use this field. However, the compiled kernel has issues booting into the system. There's no touch screen functionality and the desktop background is black. What should I be aware of when adding a field to the task_struct structure?

"I can perfectly boot into the system when I comment out this field.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.